# CMake add_custom_command ('POST_BUILD') 'DEPENDS' option is ignored

Tags: cmake

I have a **library** and a **test** projects on CMake, and I'm using this directory structure with two (project) CMakeLists.txt:

```
/
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- include/libName
|- src/...
|
|- test/
       |- CMakeLists.txt
       |- src/...
```

The outer project list defines the library, like:

`add_library(libName ${SRC} ${INCLUDE})`

And adds 'test' as subdirectory:

`add_subdirectory(test)`

The test project list defines the executable and a test, like:

```
add_executable(NameTest ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(NameTest libName)
add_test(NAME NameTest COMMAND NameTest)
```

## The problem

I'm trying to build and execute the test program when the library is built. If any test fails, I want the build of the library fail too.

This is what I have (inside the outer lists file):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET libName
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 ctest
    DEPENDS NameTest # <- This is driving me crazy!
)
```

This command ignores completely if the target 'NameTest' is built, if there is a file with that name, or if not. I can't notice any difference if the whole 'DEPENDS' option is removed.

I even modified like:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET libName
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Bip! Bip! Bip!"
    DEPENDS this_is_not_an_existent_file_nor_target
)
```

And the command is triggered anyway. I'm not very sure about if this is the option I need, so:

1. Why is this not working?
2. How can I achieve my real purpose?

Thank you.

---

Edit: ctest will execute every test (add_test), but the NameTest executable (yet listed) must be built before calling it! Now would be built **after** the library, but **before** the 'POST_BUILD' custom command. It fails, of course.

I want CMake realize NameTest is necessary for running that custom command.

---

Edit: I find useful the Angew's answer, so I accepted his answer and refined it a little bit:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET libName
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target NameTest --config $<CONFIG>
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIG> --output-on-failure
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I wrote an answer for question #1, but for #2, I actually need to know more about what your real purpose is. What are you trying to achieve with the dependency?

Comment: @Angew As you can see, the add_custom_command makes a 'make test' (Ouch! I should call cmake instead. Anyway). As NameTest is used in 'add_test' as a command, must be built to be executed. Otherwise, 'ctest' won't find the NameTest executable, and will fail.

Comment: I've edited the answer to hopefully solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is this not working?

Because you're mixing options from two distinct signatures of `add_custom_command`. `DEPENDS` comes from the form which is used to generate a file. `TARGET` and `POST_BUILD` are from the form which adds pre/post build commands to existing targets.

See the [documentation of `add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) for more details on the two uses.

> 2. How can I achieve my real purpose?

I believe the following should do what you want to:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET libName
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target NameTest --config $<CONFIG>
    COMMAND CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target test --config $<CONFIG>
)
```

Comment: You are right! I have that page (from a previous version of CMake) opened side by side, but I wrongly read "DEPENDS" in the second signature multiple times (I can't believe it!). Then, how achieve what I want? This command seems not to fit.

Comment: But that bypasses the whole CMake execution, rebuilding the library with the tests.

Comment: @NiNEngine That's strange. I would have expected that the buildsystem has already updated the library's binary by that point. But this could recurse, now that I think about it.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about it, and maybe I overlooked something. Take my previous comment with a grain of salt: I'll review it later carefully.